# Стековый контейнер является интерфейсом реального стека или всего лишь эмулирует его?

Tags: stl, стек, c++

Если это всего лишь эмуляция, то как работать со стеком напрямую?

Comment: В подавляющем большинстве задач работать напрямую со стеком программы не нужно. Мне, например, ещё ни разу не понадобилось. Если вам и _вправду_ нужно такое, C++ — не ваш язык, спускайтесь сразу на уровень ассемблера.

---
Я бы сказал, наоборот, «реальный стек» эмулирует работу абстрактной структуры данных «стек».

Answer (score 5):

Контейнер это "структура данных" LIFO,  к стеку приложения не имеет никакого отношения...

---

---

---

**UPD**

Коль мой коммент вынесли в ответ проясню пару терминов:

1. Есть структуры данных, я бы сказал
       "математическая, алгоритмическая или абстрактная"
       модель или даже "идея" (вектор,список,очередь,стек,деревья, etc)
2. Есть модель доступа к данным
       LIFO (последний пришел, первый
       ушел), FIFO(первый пришел, первый
       ушел)
3. Есть обобщённые реализации "идей" из
       пункта 1 под названием контейнеры,
       которые внутри себя могут хранить
       что угодно (типы, другие контейнеры)
4. Есть два контейнера основанных на
       модели LIFO и FIFO первый называют
       "стек" а второй "очередь"
5. Стек и очередь могут быть с
       приоритетом (в результате нарушается
       принцип LIFO и FIFO), из-за
       приоритета данные внутри контейнера
       могут храниться по-разному
       (список,дерево,вектор), связано это
       с желанием ускорить работу
       контейнера
6. При выполнении программы создаётся
       "стек приложения" или "стек
       выполнения программы", который хранится в специально отведённой части программы в ОЗУ (оперативной памяти) (при выполнении программы этот стек хранится в CPU, а при переключении  на другую задачу записывается в ОЗУ), там хранятся переменные, адреса вызова\возврата из\в функций. например в режиме дебага мы можем посмотреть "стек вызова функций", то есть стек программы без указания переменных, ну или сами переменные.
7. У процессора тоже есть свой стек
       "стек выполнения операции" в котором
       хранятся команды на ассемблере (тут
       я привираю ведь там хранятся
       машинные коды)

---

---

---

С терминологией покончено.

Собственно, как сказал  [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd),  в комментарии выше, непосредственно со "стеком процессора" или "стеком приложения" Вы можете работать только на ассемблере. Но в 99.999% из 100% Вам этого ненужно делать, а если и нужно, то скорее всего вы чего-то не того намудрили.

p.s. Если чего напутал поправьте меня в комментариях.

Comment: Проблемы терминологии. Если стек -- это LIFO, то Ваше утверждении становится бессмысленным. О терминах приходится договариваться.

Comment: @alexlz: я бы различал стек (как абстрактную структуру данных) и «стек приложения» (как конкретику имплементации вызовов функций в языке/архитектуре оборудования). Здесь в ответе именно стек приложения.

Comment: @VladD а что такое "стек приложения"? То, что обеспечивается именно командами с аутоинкрементом/аутодекрементом? Или вообще специальными командами работы со стеком (см. например AVR Tiny первого поколения -- там трёхуровнеый -- на три вызова -- аппаратный стек)? Дейкстра своё предложение об использовании стека для языков, ориентированных на блок (Algol, далее PL/I, Pascal, C и т.д.) выдвинул задолго до того, как это было использовано при проектировании процессоров.

Comment: @alexlz: ну, под стеком приложения я имею в виду кусок памяти, ассоциированный с потоком, в котором содержатся адреса возврата из процедур и их некоторые входные параметры и автоматические переменные для платформ Intel x86/x64. И их аналоги, если есть, для других платформ. Это — деталь реализации языка, которая может отсутствовать, конечно, на каких-то платформах.

А разве у понятия «стек приложения» может быть другой смысл?

Comment: @VladD а попроще вопросов нету? Потоки я впервые видел в ДОС ЕС 2.x (до трёх на задачу). Но со стеком там была напряжёнка -- аппаратного стека на "Ряд-1" (в девичестве S/360) не было.

И в более крутых (на той архитектуре) MFT/MVT со стеком так же было... Так что я в затруднении.

Comment: @alexlz: ну, где нету, там уж нету. Думаю, что ТС не учитывал в своём вопросе наличие архитектур, отличающихся от x86. :-P

Comment: @alexlz, действительно аппаратно поддерживаемого стека в S/360 не было, но насколько помню "соглашение о связях" по сути стек на S/360 моделировался связанными по R12 областями сохранения регистров.

А когда Дейкстра выдвинул свое предложение о стеке? Видимо в середине 50-х.

Не знаю, PDP-1, сделанная в 1960 была первой машиной с аппаратным стеком или нет, но IMHO не такой уж большой  срок.

Comment: @avp Поздравляю со склерозом (я сначала погуглил):

        r13 - holds address of 18-word save area

Да и рекурсия в программах не приветствовалась по причине бедности ресурсов, хотя понятие о реентерабельности уже было. Аппаратного стека не было ещё и в более современной pdp8 (которая в своё время прославила DEC), в pdp11 -- предекремент и постинкремент (если не путаю).

А работы Дейкстры, скорее всего, связаны с реализацией АЛГОЛ-60, т.е. конец 50х, а скорее начало 60х.